# Idempotent operators over the exterior algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, exterior-algebra, idempotents

I am wondering if there exists a (reasonably) well-known set of operators $A_i$ over the exterior algebra such that

$\{A_i,A_j\} = \frac{1}{2}(A_i +A_j)$,

where $\{X,Y\}=(XY+YX)/2$.

Comment: In $A \wedge A = A$, won't the LHS and RHS be forms of different sizes if they aren't zero? I mean, the wedge of two $1$ forms is a $2$ form, so it cannot be a $1$ form unless it is zero.

Comment: What if instead you required $A\wedge A = *A$?

Comment: @dst Can you give an example or a definition of operator in this context?

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution is not possible, though with you may have a solution to similar systems:

By 1), $A$ must be a function, i.e., a $0$-form, and , since the wedge of functions is their product, you must have $A==\pm 1$, But then, substituting in 2), you will have $\pm\eta+\pm\eta=\eta$, which is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with differential forms, as such.  But in geometric algebra (which supposedly encompasses differential forms), where $A$ is a k-blade and $A\wedge A= \langle AA \rangle_{2k}$, $1$ and $0$ are the only elements that satisfy the 1st property.  But neither $1$ nor $0$ hold for the 2nd.  Thus I think that there is no such element.

Comment: You could possibly get around the problem by not demanding that $A$ be a blade (or even a multivector of uniform grade).  Regardless, however, the geometric product has a much more potential for idempotents.

Comment: Assuming that the equivalent thing to a 1-form in GA is a 1-blade (i.e. vector), then from the 2nd condition $A$ must be $0.5 +$ some higher grade terms, all of which anticommute with *any* vector $\eta$.  It seems to me that the only objects which could (depending on the dimension of the space) anticommute with any vector $\eta$ is the pseudoscalar.   Thus we just need to solve $A\wedge A=A$ for some $A=0.5 + \alpha I$.  But $(0.5 + \alpha I) \wedge (0.5 + \alpha I) = 0.25 + \alpha I$.  Thus I still think there is no such element.

Comment: Perhaps I should generalize the question, $A$ need not be an element of the exterior algebra but rather an operator on forms. I am looking for a set of operators $A_i$ that satisfy $\{A_i,A_j\}=(A_i+A_j)/2$.